# SQL Server PIVOT Table: Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql-server, database, pivot-table

I need your help guys, I cant seem to figure out whats the problem with my pivot script in SQL Server

> Error Message: Incorrect syntax near '20170615'. Severity 15

```
SELECT *
FROM rev_trans
PIVOT (SUM(ABS_AMT) 
   FOR [BOOKING DATE] in ('20170614')) AS pvt
```

Thank You for your help

Comment: The way PIVOT works is that it treats anything in the `IN` part as a column name. For the same reason you wouldn't write: `WHERE 'columnName' = 123` in a where clause, you also wouldn't write `FOR ... IN ('columnName')`. Instead, use square brackets as a delimiter, like `FOR [BOOKING DATE] in ([20170614])`. Note: For column names that are pure alphabet strings and not reserved words (e.g. "columnA"), you wouldn't need square brackets, but since your column name is a number, the square brackets are required.

Comment: Please post schema for table rev_trans and sample data